# grouping & plotting by textual column value

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping

I've got a (very) basic level of competency with R when working with numbers, but when it comes to manipulating data based on text values in columns I'm stuck.  For example, if I want to plot meal frequency vs. day of week (is Tuesday really for tacos?) using the following data frame, how would I do that?  I've seen suggestions of tapply, aggregate, colSums, and others, but those have all been for slightly different scenarios and nothing gives me what I'm looking for.  Should I be looking at something other than R for this problem?  My end goal is a graph with day of week on the X-axis, count on the Y-axis, and a line plot for each meal.

```
df <- data.frame(meal= c("tacos","spaghetti","burgers","tacos","spaghetti",
"spaghetti"), day = c("monday","tuesday","wednesday","monday","tuesday","wednesday"))
```

This is as close as I've gotten, and, to be honest, I don't fully understand what it's doing:

```
tapply(df$day, df$meal, FUN = function(x) length(x))
```

It will summarize the meal counts, but a) it doesn't have column names (my understanding is that's due to tapply returning a vector), and b) it doesn't keep an association with the day of the week.

Edit:  The `melt()` suggestion below works for this dataset, but it won't scale to the size I need.  I was, however, able to get a working graph from the dataframe produced by the melt.  If anybody runs across this in the future, try:

```
ggplot(new, aes(day, value, group=meal, col=meal)) + 
geom_line() + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(x) 
unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1)))))
```

(The part after `geom_point()` is to force the Y-axis to only be integers, which is what makes sense in this case.)

Comment: That does work perfectly for this dataset, but my real set is just under 26K rows and 6 columns and it blows up melt:

`Error in table(newData) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to cut this into smaller pieces so you can understand whats going on

```
library(tidyverse)
# defining the dataframes
df <- data.frame(meal = c("tacos","spaghetti","burgers","tacos","spaghetti","spaghetti"), 
                 day = c("monday","tuesday","wednesday","monday","tuesday","wednesday"))
# define a vector of days of week ( will be useful to display x axis in the correct order)
ordered_days =c("sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday",
            "thursday","friday",'saturday')

# count the number of meals per day of week

df_count <- df %>% group_by(meal,day) %>% count() %>% ungroup()

# a lot of combinations are missing, for example no burgers on monday
# so i am creating all combinations with count 0
fill_0 <- expand.grid(
                  meal=factor(unique(df$meal)),
                  day=factor(ordered_days),
                  n=0)
# append this fill_0 to df_count
# as some combinations already exist, group by again and sum n 
# so only one row per (meal,day) combination
df_count <- rbind(df_count,fill_0) %>% 
                    group_by(meal,day) %>% 
                    summarise(n=sum(n)) %>% 
                    mutate(day=factor(day,ordered=TRUE,
                     ordered_days))

# plot this by grouping by meal
ggplot(df_count,aes(x=day,y=n,group=meal,col=meal)) + geom_line()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I'm going to need some time to marinate on this, but I just added an edit that my actual dataset is just shy of 26K rows and 6 columns.  Will this approach handle that much data?  I'm particularly wondering about the expand.grid part; I'm not familiar with it, but if it's a brute force type approach it might fall over.

Comment: it depends on the number of different combinations in your dataset, but if there are too many combinations your plot might also be hard to read

Comment: I'll give it a try; for the record, I am actually using days of the week on the X-axis, so hopefully it will be OK.  It's the "meals" that have more variables, about 20 after consolidation

Answer (score 0):

The magic is here, courtesy of @fmarm:

`df_count <- df %>% group_by(meal,day) %>% count() %>% ungroup()`

The fill_0 and rbind bits also in the sample provided by @fmarm are necessary to keep from bombing out on unspecified combinations, but it's the line above that handles summing meals by day.